# Changing BackColor of button on Click event causes hover color to change instead

Tags: c#, button, click, backcolor

There is an issue where I have a set of buttons that are supposed to act like tab buttons. I first change all the buttons' BackColors to the proper color, and then change the BackColor of the button that is clicked to a brighter color.

EDIT: Tab pressed is a method assigned to the Click event of each of the buttons i.e. btnFile, btnEdit, btnView, btnDocket, btnWidgets, and btnHelp

EDIT2: For clarification, these aren't actual tab buttons that are part of a tab control. They are regular buttons that are found in the toolbox

```
private void tabPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button tabButton = (Button)sender;
        btnFile.BackColor = btnEdit.BackColor = btnView.BackColor = btnDocket.BackColor = 
            btnWidgets.BackColor = btnHelp.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 26, 29, 42);
        Console.WriteLine(tabButton.Text);
        switch(tabButton.Text)
        {
            case "File":
                btnFile.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 39, 43, 62);
                break;
            case "Edit":
                btnEdit.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 39, 43, 62);
                break;
            case "View":
                btnView.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 39, 43, 62);
                break;
            case "Docket":
                btnDocket.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 39, 43, 62);
                break;
            case "Widgets":
                btnWidgets.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 39, 43, 62);
                break;
            case "Help":
                btnHelp.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 39, 43, 62);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

However, when this is done it seems that only the hover color of the clicked button is changed while the hover colors of the other buttons are normally colored.

[image: default]

[image: when clicked]

[image: not hovering]

[image: normal hover color]
I'm not sure what could be causing this. I thought maybe it was due to the fact that BackColor was being changed only for the hover event because it was in the hover "state" when the BackColor was changed, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you code does not have anything to do with click or hover event, it is important that which event `tabPressed` method handles.

you may in design time click on a button and select its events and make sure that `tabPressed` is selected for the click event.

to do this programmatically on runtime do it like this:

```
btnFile.Click += tabPressed;
```

Also note that you don't need a `switch-case` for this, and you can simply apply it to the sender of event (which ever button that clicked):

```
private void tabPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //your color rest codes here
   Button tabButton = (Button)sender;
   tabButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 39, 43, 62);
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I should have added more information. Tab pressed is a function I made, which is assigned to each of the buttons i.e. btnFile, btnEdit, btnView, btnDocket, btnWidgets, and btnHelp

Comment: @user3864563 Yes I got that, I said make sure that you have assigned it to their Click event, just double check it.

Comment: The method is assigned to the Click event of each button, yes